# Accessing a member of a tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

I'm curious how can I access a member of a tuple if some of the members have optional type

```
let serverResponse: (Int, String?, String?) = (statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
print(serverResponse.message)
```

I get an error

> error: value of tuple type '(Int, String?, String?)' has no member
> 'message'

Comment: This has nothing to do with optionals, you need to add the labels to the declaration of the tuple and not when assigning a value, `let serverResponse: (statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are defining,  `(Int, String?, String?)` to  `(statusCode: Int, message: String, errorMessage: String)` which are interchangeable.

If you leave the type definition empty for the variable, the type inference should provide you with the correct type.

```
let response = (statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
print(response.message)
```

Or, if you want to define the type make sure that the type is actually `(statusCode: Int, message: String, errorMessage: String)`.

```
let response: (statusCode: Int, message: String, errorMessage: String) = (statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
print(response.message)
```

You could also use tuple de-structuring syntax,

```
let (_, message, _) = (statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

You better use a `struct` for this

```
struct Response {
  let statusCode:Int 
  let message,errorMessage:String?
}
```

Then you can do

```
let item = Response(statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
print(item.message)
```

**But** with tuple use

```
print(serverResponse.1) // statusCode = 0 , message = 1 , errorMessage:String = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Either access them by their indices ($0, $1 etc) or expand the type.

```
let serverResponse: (statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?) = (statusCode: 255, message: "Welcome", errorMessage: "Error")
```